# SSH private key password never removed with Keychain/ssh-agent

Tags: password, ssh, keychain

I have an SSH private key with password, and I'm able to add it to KeyChain/ssh-agent and have the password automatically used without having to enter it.
Now I'd like to add one more thing: I want keychain/ssh-agent to *forget* (or lock) the password after a certain time elapsed or the screen is locked.

What I'm experiencing (on Mac OS X 10.9.5), is that even if I set my "login" keychain to "lock after sleep", and I wake up the laptop from sleep, and the keychain is still locked, ssh (through ssh-agent?) is still 
able to retrieve the password without asking me to unlock the keychain.

Note that the password is added to the keychain 'automatically' when I run `ssh` the first time - I'm not typing `ssh-add` on the command line, thus I prefer to not use `ssh-add -t TIMEOUT` explicitly.

Is there anyway to make it forget/lock the password?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have this settings.

[image: keychain]

Check the Keep login keychain unlocked to off, in keychain preferences - First Aid tab.

Comment: Where are these settings?